# Confused about gradle dependency handling

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

I am just getting started using Gradle.

I have created a new 'application' project using `gradle init`, which gives me a structure like this:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
│       ├── main
│       │   └── java
│       │       └── example
│       │           └── App.java
│       └── test
│           └── java
│               └── example
│                   └── AppTest.java
├── gradle
│   ├── libs.versions.toml
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
└── settings.gradle
```

In `app/src/main/java/example/App.java`, I have:

```
package example;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class App {
    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new App().getGreeting());
    }
}
```

Because of those two selenium imports, I have added selenium to my dependencies in `app/build.gradle` (following [these instructions](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/install_library/)):

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation libs.junit.jupiter
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
    testImplementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.16.1'
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

application {
    mainClass = 'example.App'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I thought this would cause `gradle build` to automatically download my dependencies and successfully  build the application. But instead I see:

```
$ gradle build
> Task :app:compileJava FAILED
/home/lkellogg/tmp/java/example/app/src/main/java/example/App.java:3: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
                          ^
/home/lkellogg/tmp/java/example/app/src/main/java/example/App.java:4: error: package org.openqa.selenium.chrome does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
                                 ^
2 errors
```

And `gradle dependencies` seems to think that I have no dependencies:

```
$ gradle dependencies
> Task :dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project 'example'
------------------------------------------------------------

No configurations
```

How do I correctly configure gradle so that it will successfully build my code?

Comment: `testImplementation` will only be available to your test code (under `src/test/java`). If you need selenium in your actual app (i.e. `src/main/java`), then you need to define it as an `implementation` dependency.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks, that was it! I wasn't clear which dependency types meant "test only" vs "test and regular build".

Comment: By default test classes have access to non-test dependencies.